# Detect x86 architecture in CMake file

Tags: x86, cmake

Is there a simple, reliable way to detect in a CMake file that the system CMake is building for is based on the **x86** instruction set (regardless of bitness)?

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. I have done extensive checking of similar questions on StackOverflow and haven't found one that actually covers this case: detecting the x86 instruction set using only CMake. I believe a solution based on searching for "x86" in `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` would work, but I'm interested in hearing other people's opinion and experience.

Comment: Okay, I agree. I'll remove that comment.

Comment: target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944060/how-to-detect-target-architecture-using-cmake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution so far:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "(x86)|(X86)|(amd64)|(AMD64)")
    set (X86 TRUE)
else ()
    set (X86 FALSE)
endif ()
```

Please complete the regular expression if you know of or find x86 systems for which `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` does not contain "x86", "X86", "amd64" or "AMD64" substrings.

Comment: `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` returns "unknown" for so many processors its mostly useless as a general solution. I'm glad its working for you. Its amazing how poorly Cmake performs as a build system.

Comment: It also returns host architecture (for me), not the target arch.