# Setup include header directories based on target architecture

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

In CMake i can add headers path for target like this:

```
target_include_directories(my_target PUBLIC /headers/path)
```

Is it possible to set specific folder for specific architecture? In xcode there are such project setting:
[XCode project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAYJW.png)
So, I need set such property in from Cmake script

I am generating XCode project by CMake. That project will build an iPhone application. As you know, iPhone have various architectures. And I have 3rd party libraries, which headers are not the same for different architectures. As you can see on image, i can setup XCode project, so every architecture would have its own headers path. But I can't find, how I could set those settings for XCode project via CMake script. That is the problem.

Comment: Yes you can and your question is somehow answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944060/how-to-detect-target-architecture-using-cmake)

Comment: Hmmm... I have read that thread before and did not find answer to my question. There are more like 'how to detect architecture'.